# ValueError: substring not found? Stuck

Tags: python, string, pandas, substring

```
df= pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df["Name"] = df["Infraction"] = df["Yards"] = ""
df[["Name", "Infraction", "Yards"]] = map(df.Detail.apply(extract))
```

This is a sample entry below.

```
val = 'Kirk Cousinspass complete short left toJamison Crowderfor 33 yards (tackle byDamontre Moore). Penalty onKory Lichtensteiger: Offensive Holding, 10 yards'
```

I have the following code.

```
df[["Name", "Infraction", "Yards"]] = list(df.Detail.apply(extract))
```

And I have an extract method that I am created.

```
def extract(entry):

split = entry.split(':')
sliced = entry.index('Penalty on') 
new_phrase =  entry[sliced:]
name_index = new_phrase.find(':')
name = new_phrase[:name_index]
second_part = new_phrase[name_index:]
infraction = second_part.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].strip()
yards_penalized = second_part.split(',')[1].strip()

return name[10:], infraction, yards_penalized
```

I am pretty sure this code is not the best way to do it, but even so I am getting this error.

```
line 8, in extract
sliced = entry.index('Penalty on') 
ValueError: substring not found
```

I know that it is bombing on that line. I tried using try, catch. Probably wrong and kind of stuck at this right now. Thanks!

Comment: so what's the issue with try/catch? It should work

Comment: Why do you say it's bombing?  Can you post `entry`?

Comment: Sounds like the data you're parsing doesn't fit the format you expect

Comment: The field that I am try to parse, when I run as a summary is a non-null object. Detail      6801 non-null object